# Convert All Subversion Branches to Git Tags Using PowerShell After a git svn

Tags: git, bash, svn, powershell, git-svn

There are lots of examples of converting Subversion *branches* to Git *tags* after performing `git svn clone` in Linux and Unix. I was able to use the steps from this blog [post](http://john.albin.net/git/convert-subversion-to-git) up to this step (step 6 in the [post](http://john.albin.net/git/convert-subversion-to-git)). I need to port the script to PowerShell. Here's the Linux version:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/tags |
cut -d / -f 4 |
while read ref
do
  git tag "$ref" "refs/heads/tags/$ref";
  git branch -D "tags/$ref";
done
```

Here's what I have so far for the PowerShell version:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/tags |
# not sure how to replace "cut"
do {
    git tag "$ref" "refs/heads/tags/$ref";
    git branch -D "tags/$ref";
} while (<# I'm assuming I'm iterating a collection but I'm not sure what or how. should this be a foreach instead? #>)
done
```

Comment: Under Windows 10 and the latest git for windows (I'm using 64-bit), the Git Bash window works great (I use it in place of PowerShell for lots of these things).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much experience with UNIX and git, so this is pretty much guessing. Try:

```
& git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/tags | % {
    #Extract the 4th field from every line
    $_.Split("/")[3]
} | % {
    #Foreach value extracted in the previous loop
    & git tag $_ "refs/heads/tags/$_"
    & git branch -D "tags/$_"
}
```